# Opencart get product downloads

Tags: php, opencart

I want to add a new tab into the products page allowing logged in customers to directly download from product page.

At first this seems simple, but it seems that opencart is missing the download_id from order_download table so maybe I am doing this all wrong.

**UPDATE**: Been doing some digging into the admin and find that opencart is actually using the filename instead of download_id so guess I will have to use that. E.g:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "order_download SET `filename` = '" . $this->db->escape($data['filename']) . "', mask = '" . $this->db->escape($data['mask']) . "', remaining = '" . (int)$data['remaining'] . "' WHERE `filename` = '" . $this->db->escape($download_info['filename']) . "'");
```

The updated method below so am I doing this correct? Seems a lot of queries so not sure if this can be improved?

```
public function getProductDownloads($product_id) {
    $data = array();

    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT download_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_download WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

    foreach ($result->rows as $product_download) {

        $product_download_query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "download d LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "download_description dd ON (d.download_id = dd.download_id) WHERE d.download_id = '" . (int)$product_download['download_id'] . "' AND dd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");

        foreach ($product_download_query->rows as $download) {  

            if (!file_exists(DIR_DOWNLOAD . $download['filename'])) continue;

            $row = array(
                'download_id' => $download['download_id'],
                'date_added'  => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($download['date_added'])),
                'name'        => $download['name'],
                'href'        => ''
            );

            if($this->customer->isLogged()){

                // 1. Get customer orders
                $order_download_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_download od LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o ON (od.order_id = o.order_id) WHERE o.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId(). "' AND o.order_status_id > '0' AND o.order_status_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_complete_status_id') . "' AND (od.remaining = -1 OR od.remaining > 0) AND od.filename = '" . $this->db->escape($download['filename']) . "'");

                foreach($order_download_query->rows as $order_download) {

                    // 2. Check customer ordered product
                    $order_product_download_query = $this->db->query("SELECT 1 FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op WHERE op.order_product_id = '" . (int)$order_download['order_product_id']. "' AND op.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

                    if($order_product_download_query->row) {

                        $row['href'] = $this->url->link('account/download/download', 'order_download_id=' . $order_download['order_download_id'], 'SSL');

                        $row['remaining'] = $order_download['remaining'];

                        break;

                    }

                }   

            }

            $data[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $data;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You don't have to run update query, after Placing order it adds data 
see `/catalog/model/checkout/order.php::addOrder()`

To download files

1. Product Must have download File
2. Order Status should be Complete
3. Download remaining should be more than 0

see `/catalog/model/account/download.php::getDownloads()`

**Solution**

add following code after `if ($product_info) {` around line 170 of `/catalog/controller/product/product.php`

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {

    $this->load->model('account/download');

    $results = $this->model_account_download->getDownloadByProduct($product_id);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if (file_exists(DIR_DOWNLOAD . $result['filename'])) {
            $size = filesize(DIR_DOWNLOAD . $result['filename']);

            $i = 0;

            $suffix = array(
                'B',
                'KB',
                'MB',
                'GB',
                'TB',
                'PB',
                'EB',
                'ZB',
                'YB'
                );

            while (($size / 1024) > 1) {
                $size = $size / 1024;
                $i++;
            }

            $this->data['downloads'][] = array(
                'order_id'   => $result['order_id'],                            
                'name'       => $result['name'],
                'remaining'  => $result['remaining'],
                'size'       => round(substr($size, 0, strpos($size, '.') + 4), 2) . $suffix[$i],
                'href'       => $this->url->link('account/download/download', 'order_download_id=' . $result['order_download_id'], 'SSL')
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Default download method fetches all downloads by customer but we need downloads on product by customer
so `/catalog/model/account/download.php` add new function. This will fetch associated downloads of product if customer have remaining download of that product.

```
public function getDownloadByProduct($product_id) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT o.order_id, o.date_added, od.order_download_id, od.name, od.filename, od.remaining FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_download od LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o ON (od.order_id = o.order_id) LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op ON (o.order_id = op.order_id) WHERE o.customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "' AND o.order_status_id > '0' AND o.order_status_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_complete_status_id') . "' AND od.remaining > 0 AND op.product_id = ' " . $product_id . " ' ORDER BY o.date_added DESC");

    return $query->rows;
}
```

now in `product.tpl` file you can echo download

```
<?php 
if(isset($downloads)){
  foreach ($downloads as $download) { ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $download['href'];?>"><?php echo $download['name'].'('.$download['remaining'].')' ?></a>
<?php   }
}
 ?>
```

Hope This helps

Comment: Thanks for this works well if the customer is logged in, but I also wanted it to display the downloads just without a link if the customer has not purchased. So they can see what is available

Comment: So it firstly gets all the downloads for a product, then second checks if customer is logged in and ordered product.

Comment: That is simple, If you want to display download only, 
you can write query to fetch data from 
download & product_to_download table

Comment: I actually want to do both, see how my code works at the start. Just looking to improve on this really ended up figuring most of it out by condition on the filename.