# OpenCart - PHP - Check if a product (download) is already purchased

Tags: php, opencart

Regarding OpenCart store selling digital downloads.

I am trying to add a script to the product page to warn the customer if that specific product (download) is already purchased and exists in Account>Downloads.
The reason is to avoid customers purchasing the same product twice.

Appreciate your help.

Edit:
I have tried getting the product IDs of all orders by a customer using a SQL query and that works fine externally but inside OpenCart I am facing issues.
A query such as:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM ocuk_order_product
WHERE order_id IN (
    SELECT order_id
    FROM ocuk_order
    WHERE customer_id = 'xxxx'
)
```

My main problem is not being sure how to get similar results in OpenCart Product page. (Which pages and path exactly and where inside the files)

Tried this post as well: [Opencart get product downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122239/opencart-get-product-downloads)
But it is not exactly working on product page (product.php)

Opencart Version 3.0.2.0

Comment: Hi Matty - that's pretty broad and SO is not a code writing service.  You'll need to check if they are a customer who's logged in, query their past order downloads, and present the data on the product page.  I'd be happy to help if you get stuck but you at least need to demonstrate that you've made an attempt here.

Comment: Sure. let me edit my post

Comment: Thanks - be sure to include the version you are working with.

Comment: Please show the query you are using and explain "works fine externally / (not) inside opencart"

Comment: A query such as "select product_id from ocuk_order_product where order_id in (select order_id from ocuk_order where customer_id = 'xxxx') " outside of OpenCart.

Comment: Ouside Opencart as in a separate SQL query such as above in a PHP application.

Comment: Please include the actual code you used *in your question* – not in a comment.  You mention that you *have a SQL query that works fine* but what is it?  I'm really trying to help you Matty - typically the way this site works, you need to present your code in a way that others can reproduce an issue.  Then we can make suggestions about how to fix the problem.  If we can't see your code we can't possibly reproduce your problem or even know what it is.

Comment: Thank you Billy and my apologies. Totally understand your point. Edited the post.  My confusion is not being sure how to get similar results to the query in OpenCart Product page.

Comment: Hmmm.. well if you run the same query on the same database it is guaranteed to return the same results.

Comment: I know but how to run this in product page. I believe there are multiple places where product page is composed in OpenCart (product php, twig, tpl etc). Where exactly I should add the query and what is the correct way of running it in a typical OpenCart page because I see $this->db->query ..... DB_PREFIX  which I am not familar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'll take a stab at this but let's clarify a few things:

1) `DB_PREFIX` is simply a php constant that's declared in your config.php file.  Based on the query you provided it's probably equal to `ocuk`.  The point is, you write queries using this constant and they become portable across installations regardless of the users' chosen database prefix.

2) Opencart is based on the MCVL (an extension of [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) which includes language files) structure. The place to execute queries is in the **model**.  The place to call model methods is in the **controller**.  The controller passes output to the *view* and often uses language variables from **language** files.

So what I would do is write function and put it in your product model – in this case that's `catalog/model/catalog/product.php`.  This function is called a *method* since it's now part of your model class.  The function will output the rows in your table that a logged in customer has purchased the given product.  It's also important to check (a) that the customer is logged in and (b) that the orders you are querying against are *real* orders - with an order_status_id > 0.  We can go into that but suffice to say that you always need to check the order_status_id if you want to know about actual completed orders.  Such a method could look something like this:

```
public function getOrderProductHistory($product_id) {
    $result = [];
    if ($customer_id = $this->customer->getId()) {
        $sql = "
            SELECT *
            FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order o
            JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op USING (order_id)
            WHERE o.order_status_id > 0
                AND o.customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'
        ";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $result = $query->rows;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Now in your controller (on a product page that's `catalog/controller/product/product.php`) you can call this method to get results like this:

```
$order_product_history = $this->model_catalog_product->getOrderProductHistory($product_id);
```

And then do something based on the output:

```
if ($order_product_history) {
    $data['has_been_ordered'] = true;
} else {
    $data['has_been_ordered'] = false;
}
```

Now `$has_been_ordered` is a boolean that you can access in your **view** to display a message to the customer.  There's still a bit more code for you to write but hopefully this helps get you off to a good start.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @Matty - Don't forget, if this answer is helpful you can "accept" it for your question by clicking the green check.  Later as you gain rep you will also be able to vote up and down.

Comment: Sure. All good. Just one more thing: I have ended up creating this $data['has_been_ordered'] = "You have already ordered this product"; ...... Now I need to make it appear in twig. I beleive I have to add something like this {{ has_been_ordered }} but it is not showing up

Comment: @Matty - I'm glad you figured that part out.  Are you going to accept my answer?